# How to improve an entity framework query with multiple deep includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a query using Entity Framework 5 which is used to populate an Order view.  The view shows the complete order details, all order items, the associated products, images, discounts, product options etc..

The query below generates a huge SQL query (as you would expect), as it has to return multiple rows to include all child properties, and the performance is horrible.

What is the best way to split this up?  I assume I can either split this into multiple database calls (but how?) and/or use projection to just pull the properties required in the viewmodel.

```
            var order = context.Orders
                    .Include("OrderItems.Product.ProductSubTypeRange.ProductRange.Supplier")
                    .Include("OrderItems.Product.ProductSubTypeRange.ProductSubType.ProductType")
                    .Include("OrderItems.Product.ProductMaterial")
                    .Include("OrderItems.Product.ProductImages.Image")
                    .Include("OrderItems.Product.ProductImages.ImageLabel")
                    .Include("OrderItems.OrderItemOptions.ProductOption.ProductOptionType")
                    .Include("OrderItems.OrderItemOptions.ProductOption.ProductOptionGroup.ProductOptionType")                      
                    .Include("OrderSamples.Product.ProductSubTypeRange.ProductRange")
                    .Include("OrderSamples.Product.ProductSubTypeRange.ProductSubType.ProductType")
                    .Include("OrderSamples.Product.ProductMaterial")
                    .Include("OrderSamples.Product.ProductImages.Image")
                    .Include("OrderSamples.Product.ProductImages.ImageLabel")
                    .Include("OrderAccessories.Accessory.AccessorySubType.AccessoryType")
                    .Include("OrderAccessories.Accessory.AccessoryImages.Image")
                    .Include("OrderAccessories.Accessory.AccessoryImages.ImageLabel")
                    .Include("OrderAccessories.OrderAccessoryOptions.AccessoryOption.AccessoryOptionType")
                    .Include("OrderAccessories.OrderAccessoryOptions.AccessoryOption.AccessoryOptionGroup.AccessoryOptionType")
                    .Include("OrderAccessorySamples.Accessory.AccessorySubType.AccessoryType")
                    .Include("OrderDiscounts.Discount.DiscountProducts.Product")
                    .Include("OrderDiscounts.Discount.DiscountProductSubTypes.ProductSubType")
                    .Include("Customer")
                    .Include("PaymentTransactions")
                    .Include("Emails");
```

Comment: You probably should load data separately, either explicitly so you cache them in the context, or later, on demand.

Comment: Can you expand on how exactly to go about doing that?  I'm not sure how to load in separate queries?